# How to add quotation mark to existing text in a csv file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I need to convert strings in a csv file to strings with quotation marks around it.

My csv file looks like this:

```
Description;AllowHosts;SPNs;Owner
 
Description1;server1$, server2$, server3$;MSSQLSvc/PD01.dom1.com:1521,MSSQLSvc/PD01.dom1;Owner JDOE
Description2;server4$, server5$, server6$;MSSQLSvc/PD02.dom2.com:1521,MSSQLSvc/PD02.dom2;Owner JDOE
Description3;server7$, server8$, server9$;MSSQLSvc/PD03.dom1.com:1521,MSSQLSvc/PD03.dom1;Owner JDOE
```

I tried to search for header `"AllowHosts"` and replace with quotation mark in start and end,

```
$csv = @(
Import-Csv -Path $New -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8
)

$data = ConvertFrom-Csv $csv
$Data[0].AllowHosts = '"'

$Data | where AllowHosts -Like '*$' | foreach {
    $_.AllowHosts = '*$"'
}
$Data | where AllowHosts -Like 'SF' | foreach {
  $_.AllowHosts = '"SF*'
}
$Data | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

but it did not work as expected....

I would like to have quotation mark around each string

1. in column `"AllowHosts"` (servernames)
2. in column `"SPNs"`

I am hoping for a result like this:

```
Description;AllowHosts;SPNs;Owner
Description1;"server1$", "server2$", "server3$";"MSSQLSvc/PD01.dom1.com:1521","MSSQLSvc/PD01.dom1";Owner JDOE
Description2;"server4$", "server5$", "server6$";"MSSQLSvc/PD02.dom2.com:1521","MSSQLSvc/PD02.dom2";Owner JDOE
Description3;"server7$", "server8$", "server9$";"MSSQLSvc/PD03.dom1.com:1521","MSSQLSvc/PD03.dom1";Owner JDOE
```

But how?

I have a powershell script that imports csv-file and creates json-files. My problem is that this line

```
"      ""PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword"""+": [" | Out-File $filepath1 -Append
```

gives this result

```
"PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword": [ "server1$, server2$, server3$"  ],
```

instead of

```
"PrincipalsAllowedToRetrieveManagedPassword": [ "server1$", "server2$", "server3$"  ],
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Your desired output wouldn't be a well-formed CSV file, because if you want a field to contain `"` characters, you must double them _and_ enclose the whole field in `"..."`

Comment: Related to mklement0's comment on well-formed CSV, it may be useful if you share the larger goal or intent.  If you are not wanting the results to be a CSV, then what file format are you wanting?  Is this intended for use with some specialized software that requires a unique format?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am using the csv-file to enrich json-files. I have added some more description of this in the buttom... I was not able to decode the powershell regex (?) part myself so I was seeking an answer in converting my csv-file. Please see additional info in buttom of my original post.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-replace` operator to add `"`'s around each "word" in the string:

```
# read data into memory
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $New -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8

# modify all `AllowHosts` and `SPN` cells
$csv |ForEach-Object {
    $_.AllowHosts = $_.AllowHosts -replace '([^\s,]+)','"$1"'
    $_.SPNs = $_.SPNs -replace '([^\s,]+)','"$1"'
}

# re-export
$csv |Export-Csv -Path path\to\export.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The pattern `([^\s,]+)` matches (and captures) any consecutive sequence of characters *not* containing `,` or whitespace, and the substitution string `"$1"` expands to "".

Beware that this introduces *ambiguity*, as `"`'s are also used as *value qualifiers* in CSVs - so `Export-Csv` will escape the quotation marks you've added to retain them, and the resulting file will look like this:

```
"Description","AllowHosts","SPNs","Owner"
"Description1","""server1$"", ""server2$"", ""server3$""","""MSSQLSvc/PD01.dom1.com:1521"",""MSSQLSvc/PD01.dom1""","Owner JDOE"
"Description2","""server4$"", ""server5$"", ""server6$""","""MSSQLSvc/PD02.dom2.com:1521"",""MSSQLSvc/PD02.dom2""","Owner JDOE"
"Description3","""server7$"", ""server8$"", ""server9$""","""MSSQLSvc/PD03.dom1.com:1521"",""MSSQLSvc/PD03.dom1""","Owner JDOE"
```